# Upgrading Redmi 5 3gb 32 gb motherboard to a 4 gb 64 gb motherboard

Tags: ram, redmi

I have Redmi 5 3 gb and 32 gb rom which is in good condition.
Now, I want to upgrade the memory specs to 4 gb and 64 gb without changing the phone.
Is it possible to remove the old motherboard and replaced with a new Redmi 5 4 gb 64 gb rom motherboard???
Please kindly help me with upgrading my memory specs instead of buying a brand new phone.

Answer (score 1):

A smartphone is not like a PC where you can replace components. Additionally a smartphone mainboard contains everything soldered on it, which means that CPU, RAM, Flash-memory, sensors, and next to everything may be except from external components like display and camera module is an integral part of the mainboard.

Note that even if displays have the same size and all other technical details this does not mean that they are compatible.

So in the what you want has a very small chance that it is possible. Replacing the mainboard has only disadvantages (no warranty, high chance to destroy something,...).

So in the end it is better to buy a working new/used phone, otherwise most likely every money you spend on replacing the mainboard are lost and better spent on a new phone.